# Does the pixel count of the image sensor equate to the number of pixels of the image?

Tags: sensor, megapixels

The Canon EOS 5D Mark IV has a 30.4 megapixel sensor.

Does that mean that it can produce ~30 megapixel images?

Comment: Just for the record Canon EOS 5D is 12.8MP camera (sensor have 13.3 megapixels)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think OP is talking about the 5Dmk4 (30.4MP)

Comment: @twalberg is spot on. From a marketing perspective, it would only confuse the market if the number of output MP's is listed alongside the actual pixel count of the sensor. The actual pixel count might be important to some, but the *effective* pixel count is important to all.

Comment: @Hueco Canon often includes both numbers on the spec sheets for their cameras. For instance, they list the EOS 5D Mark IV with  31.7 million 'total pixels' and 30.4 'Megapixels'.

Answer (score 3):

That's what it generally means when a manufacturer says that their camera has so many mega-pixels - that the largest image it will produce has that many pixels in it (give or take rounding off). The sensor generally has more sensels than that, because each sensel only records one level value after passing through a colored filter, and algorithms are used to convert those filtered levels into the final red/green/blue pixels you're familiar with. In addition, in many cases, some of the sensor area is used for metering and focusing.

Comment: If than ,how much average output megapixels can we achieve from the sensor?

Comment: If your camera is a 30 megapixel camera, then you will get 30 megapixels from the sensor, after all the in-camera algorithms have done their work to convert the raw voltage levels read out from the sensels to pixels.

Comment: What's a sensel?

Comment: @Hueco ["_A single sensor element of an array of sensors, such as in a charge-coupled device._"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensel)

Answer (score 3):

> Does the pixel count of the image sensor equate to the number of pixels of the image?

No, because sensors do not really have *pixels*. A lot of folks, including the marketing departments of major camera manufacturers, may say a sensor has *x* number of pixels. But what they mean is that a sensor has *x* number of sensels or photosites that create an image file with *x* number of "effective" pixels. (Isn't language wonderful? We can say things a certain way when we really mean something else, and everyone else is expected to understand what we *mean*, rather than what we *say*!)

The smallest unit on most imaging sensors is a [*sensel*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensel),defined at wiktionary as: *A single sensor element of an array of sensors, such as in a charge-coupled device.*. Sensels are sometimes referred to as "discreet photosites."

Only the output of an imaging sensor has *pixels*, defined at wiktionary as: *One of the tiny dots that make up the representation of an image in a computer's memory*.

**The number of sensels on an imaging sensor can vary anywhere from very little to greatly from the number of pixels in the image files output by the camera system that contains the sensor and processes the output from the sensor into a digital image file.**

With traditional CMOS sensors, most of the sensels of an imaging sensor are represented by a corresponding pixel in the camera's output. But there are some sensels at the very edge of the sensor that are used to do the interpolations needed for demosaicing three channel color values from the monochromatic luminance values produced by each sensel. Since pretty much all demosaicing algorithms depend on the measurement of surrounding sensels to assign color values to each monochromatic sensel, the last row or column of pixels in a camera's output needs a few additional rows of sensels on the edge of the sensor to have the data needed to calculate those color values. Additionally, some sensels on many sensors may be masked from light in order to measure the amount of camera generated noise affecting each exposure. Depending on the camera, some interior pixels may also be physically or electronically masked out for various reasons. Among those reasons are mapping out "hot, dead, or stuck pixels (sic)" and mapping out sensels used for some types of main imaging sensor based autofocus. The values for these mapped out pixels in the output file are usually interpolated from the values of surrounding pixels.

Another thing that can cause the number of pixels in an image to vary from the number of sensels used to capture that image are ways we might process/manipulate a sensor's output to do things such as 'geometric distortion correction' or 'tilting'. As the information from each sensel is "warped' or "stretched" or "tilted", the grid of sensels on the image sensor no longer has a one-to-one correspondence to the grid of pixels in the resulting image file. The next time you are using a crop/rotate tool, notice that if you first crop an image and then rotate it a few degrees or fractions thereof, that the width and height, in pixels, of the cropped portion of the image can change with each adjustment to the exact angle you are tilting it!

Cameras that automatically do distortion correction or use forms of digital image stabilization often output files with fewer pixles than the number of photosites on the sensor.

There are newer sensor designs that use millions more sensels than the number of pixels the image files from such sensors contain. Any of Canon's sensors with 'Dual Pixel CMOS AF' are an example of this. The most discrete unit of measurement on such sensors is what some call a 'sub-pixel' - each square on a CMOS sensor that would normally be a single photosite is divided into two rectangular photosites. The overlaid microlenses in front of each such pair of sensels are pointed at different angles so that one is more influenced by light coming through one side of the lens and the other one of each pair is more influenced by light coming from the same point in the scene via the opposite  side of the lens.¹ The differences between the output of several sets of such pairs is used to calculate how in or out of focus, and in which direction, the subject is. With sensors designed for 'Dual Pixel CMOS AF', around eighty percent of the width and height of the the sensor is covered by photosites that are half of a pair that will equate to a single pixel in the sensor's raw data output. Therefore, such sensors have almost twice as many discreet photosites, or sensels, as the digital output from such sensors have pixels.

[image]

[image]

<sub>¹ Please remember that the light from every point in the field of view strikes every point on the front of the lens (unless something - such as a filter ring or the barrel of a lens - blocks that light from part, but not all, of the front of the lens). Light from the parts of the field of view at the lens' focus distance are refocused by the lens to a (hopefully) single point on the image projected by the lens onto the imaging sensor.</sub>